# Re-initialize a Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a **JQuery** plug in, inside of which I initialize the **Affix** plugin of **Bootstrap**, to fix the left menu of a webpage. Here I post a runnable example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  .affix {
    top: 20px;
  }

  .affix {
        top: 20px;
        z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
    .affix-bottom {
        position: relative;
        width: 213px;
    }
  </style>


  <script>


  (function ($) {
        $.fn.affixManager = function (options) {

            var init = function(){
                $('.nav').affix({offset: {
                    top: $('#header').outerHeight(true),
                    bottom: $('#footer').outerHeight(true)
                    }
                });
            }

            init();
        }
    }(jQuery));


  $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).affixManager();


          $(window).on("resize", function() {
                //  here I want to re-initialize the plugin, because I need to update
                //  the top and bottom properties
           });
   });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;height:200px" id="header">

</div>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="background-color:#cccccc;height:700px">

  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

When users resize the window, I want to remove the previous plugin and add new one, because I need to re-set the **top** and **bottom** properties of the Affix function, calling once again `$('#header').outerHeight(true)` and `$('#footer').outerHeight(true)`.

**PS**: in this example I set fixed height for header and footer. Actually they aren't fixed. This is the reason why I need to recalculate `$('#header').outerHeight(true)` and  `$('#footer').outerHeight(true)`.

What's the right way to do it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post a runnable example? Because the plugin you posted has some structural issues. Why returning the output variable outside the plugin?

Comment: Hi @Kalimah, i posted a runnable example. Do you have any idea about the solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinitialize the plugin. You can capture the resize event inside the plugin and re-initiate affix. I fixed your plugin so it is performed on the element itself not window object.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.affixManager = function(options) {

    const el = jQuery(this);

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      $(window).off('.affix')
      el.removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom')
      init();
    });

    var init = function() {
      el.affix({
        offset: {
          top: $('#header').outerHeight(true),
          bottom: $('#footer').outerHeight(true)
        }
      });
    }

    init();
  }
}(jQuery));


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav").affixManager();
});
```

```css
.affix {
  top: 20px;
}

.affix {
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.affix-bottom {
  position: relative;
  width: 213px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;height:200px" id="header">

</div>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="background-color:#cccccc;height:700px">

  </div>
</div>
```

Resources:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23797510/529024
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37891578/529024

Comment: Thank you man. Actually I already tried a code very similar to yours, with the same logic; the problem is when you resize the page: in reality I don't have a fix height for header and footer. In some cases, when you resizes the page, and header and footer get higher or smaller, the left menu overflaps the footer; in some other cases the left menu stays fixed at the bottom, without moving when you scroll up. Anyway, I'll try to mix up your code and mine, to see if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This way the problems seems to be corrected. I tested it with IE(9,10,11,EDGE), Chrome, Opera, Firefox. Plus, I manage the left menù size, to be as bis as the column in which it is contained (Bootstrap applies a fixed width along with affix class). I even added a fixed top menu, to be sure my plugin addresses only the "affix menu" I want and not all the ones present in the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>


/* classi ad applicare per gestire il menu affix*/
 #leftMenu.affix {
  top: 80px; /*Questo attributo deve corrispondere all'attributo topAttributeAffixClass della funzione*/
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

 #leftMenu.affix-bottom {
  position: relative;
}
/* ******************************** */

/* classi affix per top menu; servono solo a titolo di esempio, per
assicurare che la funzione gestisce in maniera corretta il menu di sinistra,
senza impattare sul menu nella testata*/
#topMenu.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
  }

#topMenu.affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
/* *********************** */
</style>


  <script>
  (function($) {
      $.fn.affixManager = function(options) {

          /*impostazioni di default*/
          var settings = $.extend({
              /*Il valore dell'attributo top applicato alla classe affix*/
              topAttributeAffixClass: 80,
              /*Il valore dello spazio da aggiungere all'attributo top della funzione affix*/
              topOffset: -20,
              /*Il valore dello spazio da aggiungere all'attributo bottom della funzione affix*/
              bottomOffset: 50,
              /*Il selettore del container che raggruppa tutti gli element presenti prima del menu affix, allo
              scroll del quale il menu va in affix*/
              topContainerSelector : "#header",
              /*Il selettore del container che raggruppa tutti gli element presenti dopo il menu affix, alla
              visualizzazione del quale il menu non è più affix, ma scrolla insieme alla pagina*/
              bottomContainerSelector : "#footer",
              /*la classe che identifica l'oggetto contenitore dell'oggetto al quale applicare l'affix*/
              affixElementContainerClass: ".affix-menu-container"
          },
          options);           

        //const el = jQuery(this); //non funzione su <IE10
        var el = jQuery(this);

        $(window).on("resize", function() {
            $(".nav").removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom');
            $(".nav").css("top", settings.topAttributeAffixClass);
            $(window).off('.affix');
            el.removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom');
            $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top
              }, 0);
          init();        
        });

        var init = function() {             
            resizeAffixContainer();
            el.affix({
                offset: {
                    top: $(settings.topContainerSelector).outerHeight(true) + settings.topOffset,
                    bottom: $(settings.bottomContainerSelector).outerHeight(true) + settings.bottomOffset,           
                }
            });
        }

        /*Funzione che prende la dimensione del contenitore dell'elemento al quale applicare l'affix, rimuove il padding e applica
        la medesima dimensione all'elemento al quale si applica l'affix*/
        var resizeAffixContainer = function(){          
            el.css("width", parseInt($(settings.affixElementContainerClass).css("width").replace("px","")) -  
                  parseInt($(settings.affixElementContainerClass).css("padding-left").replace("px","")) - 
                  parseInt($(settings.affixElementContainerClass).css("padding-right").replace("px","")));
        }

        init();
      }
    }(jQuery));


    $(document).ready(function() {
       /*l'id del menu al quale applicare l'affix*/
      $("#leftMenu").affixManager();
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Il contenitore che raggruppa tutti gli element presenti prima del menu affix, allo scroll del quale il menu va in affix*/ -->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;" id="header">
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
        bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
    </div>

    <!-- Il menu principale al quale applicare l'affix, ma che non viene gestito dal plugin affixManager() -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix"id="topMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-sm-3 affix-menu-container">
                <!-- Il menu al quale applicare il plugin affixManager() -->
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="leftMenu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
                  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Il container che raggruppa tutti gli element presenti dopo il menu affix, alla visualizzazione del quale il menu non è più affix, ma scrolla insieme alla pagina -->
        <div id="footer" style="background-color:#cccccc">
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
             bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
             bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
             bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
             bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla v
            bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
      </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```